# How to adjust the space bar and enter works only for third button and not for any other button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

https://jsfiddle.net/ffkwgddL/

There are three buttons in my code first-button, second-button and third-button if I click my first-button i.e introduction and then press space bar it again works as I have clicked first button but if I click first button and then third button i.e click to get next content and then press space it works as I am clicking third button. I want that the space bar and enter works only for third button and not for any other button and sorry my fiddle doesn't looks that great as it was only for land scape view.

```
<body>
<div class="container" id="wrapper">
<div class="top">
<div class="heading">
  <h1>Multiples</h1>
</div>
 </div>
 <div class="main-content">
 <div class="content-left col-xs-3">
  <div class="btns" role="group" aria-label="...">

    <button class="btn btn-default .btn-lg text-break first-button">Introduction<br>
     </button>
    <br>
    <button class="btn btn-default .btn-lg text-break second-button">Properties of Multiples</button>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content-right col-xs-9">
  <div class="content-first-button">
    <div class="button1_text1 well well-lg">A <b><i>multiple</i></b> is the product of the given numbers and some other counting numbers.</div>
    <div class="button1_text2">
      <div class="button1_text2_1"><b>e.g.-</b></div>
      <div class="button1_text2_2"><br>
        When we multiply the number by <b>1, 2, 3, 4 ....</b>and so on, </div>
      <div class="button1_text2_3">We get multiples of that number.</div>
      <div class="button1_text3"><b>Multiples of 3</b></div>
      <center>
        <div class="button1_text4">
          <p class="abcd"><b>1&nbsp&nbsp;</b> x <b>&nbsp&nbsp;3</b> &nbsp&nbsp;= <b> &nbsp&nbsp;3</b></p>
          <p><b>2&nbsp&nbsp;</b> x <b>&nbsp&nbsp;3</b> &nbsp&nbsp;= <b> &nbsp&nbsp;6</b></p>
          <p><b>3&nbsp&nbsp;</b> x <b>&nbsp&nbsp;3</b> &nbsp&nbsp;= <b> &nbsp&nbsp;9</b></p>
          <p class="abcde"><b>&nbsp&nbsp;4&nbsp&nbsp;</b> x <b>&nbsp&nbsp;3</b> &nbsp&nbsp;= <b> &nbsp&nbsp;12</b></p>
        </div>
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="button2_text1"><b>Properties of Multiples</b></div>
    <div class="button2_text2">
      <ul class="fa-ul">
        <li> <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i> <b class="button2_text2_1">Every number is a multiple of itself</b> </li>
      </ul>
      <br>
      <b class="button2_text2_2"><i>i.e.</i></b> <b class="button2_text2_3">1 &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp;x&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp 15 &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp; = &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp;15</b></div>
    <br>
    <div class="button2_text3">
      <ul class="fa-ul">
        <li> <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i> <b class="button2_text3_1">The least multiple of a number is number itself</b>     </li>
      </ul>
      <b class="button2_text3_2">1 &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp;x&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp 15 &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp; = &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp;15</b> <b class="button2_text3_3"><i>least multiple</i></b> <br>
      <b class="button2_text3_4">2 &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp;x&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp 15 &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp; = &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp;30</b><br>
      <b class="button2_text3_5">3 &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp;x&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp 15 &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp; = &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp;45</b><br>
      <b class="button2_text3_6">4 &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp;x&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp 15 &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp; = &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp;60</b><br>
    </div>
    <div class="button3_text3_7 well well-lg"<b>Every multiple of a number is completely divisible by that number</b> </div>
  <div class="button3_text3_8">
    <ul class="fa-ul">
      <li> <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><b class="abcdefg">Every number is a multiple of 1</b> </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="button3_text3_9">
    <ul class="fa-ul">
      <li> <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <div class="abcdef">There is no end to multiples of a number, hence there is no highest multiple of a number.</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
 </div>
 <div class="footer">
<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3"></div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3"></div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
  <button class="btn btn-default .btn-lg text-break third-button">Click to get next content</button>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="warning-message"> this website is only viewable in landscape mode     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the `$(".first-button").blur();` or `$(this).blur();` to your click functions to unfocus the button when it is focused (like click event for button). example:

```
$(".first-button").click(function(){
   ...all your code...
   $(".first-button").blur(); //or '$(this).blur();' instead
   setTimeout(function(){ $(".third-button").focus(); }, 3000);
}
```

Check the [Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/ffkwgddL/6/)

I have only done it for the `first-button`, you can do the same for second as well.

**Updated :**
Since your `third-button` takes some time to fadein, you can add a `setTimeout()` of say about 3s and then focus it on the third. Fiddle Updated

Comment: thanks for ur answer, but its just half my solution i have used blur function and have set focus on my third button but focus is not working correctly.

Comment: I can see `$(this).focus();` inside `$(".first-button").click(function()` you don't need to use focus there, you need `blur()` there. Any reason why you need it there ? Check my Fiddle in the answer

Comment: there is no $(this).focus(); instead there is $('.third-button').focus(); because i want my third button to be clicked when space bar is being used

Comment: In the above case when you click "introduction" button then press space "click to get next contents" will be **automatically** called. No need to use `focus()` anywhere.

Comment: Yes this happens **automatically** when you use `blur()` on first, no need to use `focus()` on third button. Try pressing space & check

Comment: its not working brother when i press first button then i want by pressing space bar my content is shown but unless i click third button once space bar is not working please check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124996/discussion-between-nikhil-nanjappa-and-nitish-dhawan).

Comment: check the discussion page